# background featured image display using shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I created a slider shortcode in my custom theme. My sliders images display at the background image. I don't know how can I display background slider images using shortcode

Here is my code:

```php
 $string .=' <div class="main-slider-item" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">' . 
            ' <div class="d-table">' . 
                ' <div class="d-table-cell">' . 
                    '<div class="container">'.
                        ' <div class="main-slider-content">' .
                        '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>' .
                        get_the_content() .
                        ' <div class="slider-btn">'.
                        '<a href="'.$slider_buttons1link.'" class="default-btn">' .  $slider_buttons1txt . '</a>' .
                        '<a href="'.$slider_buttons2link.'" class="default-btn-two">' .  $slider_buttons2txt . '</a>' .
                        '</div>'.
                        ' </div>' . 
                    '</div>' .
                ' </div>'. 
            ' </div>' . 
            '</div>';
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a PHP tag inside a string, that won't work, you need to concatenate the two, e.g. `"foo" . $variable . "bar"`, not `"foo<?php echo $variable; ?>bar"`

Comment: I understand what you say. But i can't understand how can i use it in my code

Comment: It's a basic PHP thing, you either are in PHP or you aren't, so this for example makes no sense: `<p><?php echo "test<?php echo "123"; ?>45"; ?>`, you cannot nest PHP tags, it doesn't make sense. Your HTML is inside a PHP string, so join the string up instead. e.g. `"hello " . "world"` = `"hello world"`

Comment: `echo "html stuff <?php echo your background ?>"more html";` -> `echo "html stuff". display your background . "more html";`